# (C#) TcpClient does not connect to irc server (Using a number ip)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tcpclient, bots, irc

So, I have been trying to make a bot that connects to a local irc server. The problem is that if I call the "Irc.cs" class I made with a constructor like: `Irc irc = new Irc("192.168.1.2", 6667); irc.joinChannel("#test")`  it does not show up on the irc server channel. The thing is I don't think it failed to connect because if I put `Irc irc = new Irc("192.168.1.11", 6667)` (which isn't a server) it throws an exception, but the one that is a server doesn't. I would love if someone could help :) This is the code for "Irc.cs"

```
        public IrcBot(String ip, int port, String nickName)
    {

        tcpClient = new TcpClient(ip, port);
        inputStream = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream());
        outputStream = new StreamWriter(tcpClient.GetStream());

        outputStream.WriteLine("NICK " + nickName);
        outputStream.WriteLine("USER " + nickName + " 8 * : " + nickName);
        outputStream.Flush();
    }

        public void joinRoom(String channel)
    {
        this.channel = channel;

        outputStream.WriteLine("JOIN " + channel);
        outputStream.Flush();
    }
```

Comment: PS: Port 6667 is open. I can connect to the irc server (hosted on a VM) on my normal pc using mIRC

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe you send the join command too soon. I do know that connecting to an IRC server takes some time. Right now you don't wait for any response. Apart from that I suggest to close and dispose streams (e.g. using using)

Comment: @RonDeijkers Ok so how would I check if Im getting a response

Comment: by reading the input stream. I don't know about the IRC protocol so I don't know which commands will be returned. A thorough reading of the IRC protocol can answer that and you could additionally use WireShark in combination with an IRC client like mIRC to check how the communication works. I also do think however that it is more than likely that all IRC servers will check for bots.

Comment: @RonDeijkers Well would my own server block bots on its own?

Comment: you would need to dive into the documentation of the installed IRC server to check for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One important thing here is that IRC uses CR/LF instead of LF that StreamWriters use, so you would need to create a StreamWriter like this:

```
writer = new StreamWriter(stream) { NewLine = "\r\n" };
```

That way it will send CR/LF at the end of each line.

Comment: Ok. It still didn't show up  as a bot in the channel.

Comment: Now it says Working...
`:irc.test.com NOTICE * :*** Looking up your hostname...
:irc.test.com NOTICE * :*** Couldn't resolve your hostname; using your IP address instead
PING :B6598BF5` ThisIsANames is the nick i set
ERROR :Closing Link: ThisIsANames[192.168.1.5] (Registration Timeout)